# How does the .All(db1 => db1.Text != wb.Text)) in LINQ work when comparing two lists?

Tags: c#, linq

I recently asked this question about how to compare two lists and check for the items that were added in the new.

I have two objects of type IList:

```
public class SampleSentence
{
    public int SampleSentenceId { get; set; } 
    public string Text { get; set; } 
}

IList<SampleSentence> Old = 
   [new SampleSentence() { SampleSentenceId = 1; Text = 'cat' }]

IList<SampleSentence> New = 
   [new SampleSentence() { Text = 'cat' }],
    new SampleSentence() { Text = 'dog' }]
```

What I need to get is:

```
IList<SampleSentence> whatINeed = 
   [new SampleSentence() { Text = 'dog' }]
```

- Object `Old` is a list of SampleSentences with the SampleSentenceId and Text fields populated.
- Object `New` is a list of SampleSentences with the only the Text fields populated. It will have the same or more rows than object `Old`

Using LINQ how can I compare the `Old` and `New` objects (linking them with the contents of Text) and create another IList that has the additional columns in the list named `New`?

**1.** The answer I received seems to work:

```
IList<SampleSentence> whatINeed = New.GroupJoin(Old,
    newElement => newElement.Text, oldElement => oldElement.Text,
    (newElement, oldElements) => new { newElement, oldElements })
.Where(match => !match.oldElements.Any())
.Select(match => match.newElement)
.ToList();
```

**2.** But I also came up with this answer myself.

```
var addS = sampleSentences
              .Where(wb => oldObjS
              .All(db1 => db1.Text != wb.Text))
              .ToList();
```

This 2nd answer seems to work also but I am not sure why. Can someone explain if these two coding methods are the same and explain how .ALL works in this context? Can anyone see a reason why the second method would not work in all cases?

Comment: The straight forward solution is to use [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are **functionally** equivalent.

In order to understand why, you need to realize that `All` and `Any` extension methods are interchangeable in way that

```
All(condition) == !Any(!condition)
```

so your query #2 criteria

```
Where(wb => oldObjS.All(db1 => db1.Text != wb.Text))
```

is equivalent to

```
Where(wb => !oldObjS.Any(db1 => db1.Text == wb.Text))
```

or showing it differently

```
Where(wb => !oldObjS.Where(db1 => db1.Text == wb.Text).Any())
```

If we constitute (just artificially, below is not a valid construct)

```
match = oldObjS.Where(db1 => db1.Text == wb.Text)
Where(wb => !match.Any())
```

then as you can see we get the query #1.

The difference is **how** the match is performed, hence the **performance**. The join based query is using hash based implementation for performing the match, so it has **O(N + M)** time complexity while the second query has to perform linear search from each element of the first set, thus having **O(N * M)** time complexity, where **N** is `New.Count`, **M** is `Old.Count`.

Of course the above applies only to LINQ to Objects and is not so important for LINQ queries against real `IQueryable` providers, because they can analyze the expression tree and actually translate both variants to one and the same SQL query, and even they don't do that, then the same can be done by the database SQL optimizers.